# How are the number various ulimit values for a process set?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ps

Description:    Ubuntu 13.10

How are the various ulimit values for a process set ? I am especially interested in the number of open file descriptors. How is that set for a given process ? If it is based on the user who started the process then how is it set for the user ?

How can I set these limits for a particular user ?

Comment: You should probably try asking/searching on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only set when code explicitly chooses to set it. Otherwise, processes inherit the settings of their parent process. Login shells typically set resource limits based on configuration settings. On Linux, this is typically controlled by the [pam_limits](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_limits) library and files like `/etc/security/limits.conf`.